# Apache Cordova Application Not Updating

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm getting started with Apache Cordova so far I've got it install via Node.js and I have all the necessary SDKs and libraries installed and linked up.

I'm modifying my source html/js/css using JetBrains WebStorm on Windows 8.

I'm testing my applications on my 1st generation Nexus 7.

The key issue I'm having at the moment is when I go to re-build and run my application on the Nexus 7.

Changes to my JS reflect immediately between builds and runs such as:

`console.log("Hello World");` to `console.log("Hello Cordova");`

However changes to the HTML such as:

`<title>Hello World</title>` to `<title>Hello Cordova</title>`

Take ages to reflect in the applications.

I assume there's some sort of cache on the device that isn't being cleared between builds?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, but try using below preference in config.xml:

```
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false" />
```

Comment: Cheers I think that fixed the issue. Can you provide me with any helpful resources relating to "Getting Started" with Apache Cordova other than the official documentation?

Comment: not sure buddy. Even i feel extremely difficult finding answers when I have questions. I went with cordova 3.0 but the File API did not work properly (file was creating, but data was not written). After 3 days of struggling, I moved on to 2.9 and everything was smooth